# How do I get users with a specific email domain from PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, email

I want to get all users with a specific domain in their email. How can I accomplish this with a PostgreSQL command so I don't need to fetch all the users and then filter them out with Ruby?

```
where('user.email == ?', '*@domain.com')
```

What's the most efficient way to do this? `split` and then `join`? Or is there a super command in PostgreSQL that you can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the ["`like`"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html) command.

In particular you want something similar to:

```
'user.email like "%?"'
```

The `%` is a wildcard in `like` clauses, that tells PostgreSQL to find the string given at the end of the field being searched.

PostgreSQL supports regular expressions also, but `like` should be sufficient for what you're after.

Comment: Great
This worked for me:

User.where("email LIKE ?", "%@domain.com")

Comment: Ah, yes, Active Record would wrap `?` in the correct quotes, so a bare `?` would work. It's been a while since I've used Active Record for my ORM.

Comment: Offtopic, what do you use instead?

Comment: I'm a big fan of the [Sequel ORM](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/index.html) gem. It requires very little SQL to be written, but can accept it if you choose.

Comment: @theTinMan I've seen good things mentioned about that, but also a lot of reports of buggy flakeyness. What's your experience? (I'm a non-Ruby non-Rails user who likes the idea of a useful RAD tool, but as a DBA and small-time PostgreSQL developer I can't stand the horror that is ActiveRecord)

Comment: I've never seen a problem with Sequel. I've looked at its generated SQL many times and it's always been sane. We use it in production where it's handling a decent number of database interactions daily; I'd estimate around 100K/day minimum. In the past I used it heavily in a big RSS aggregator handling thousands of feeds, talking to sharded PostgreSQL DBs without it ever having a hiccup. I imagine someone could push it into a corner and get it to act up; *EVERY* ORM will do that when not used as recommended/intended.

Comment: I agree about Active Record. It works, and it's battle hardened, but I've never felt comfortable using it. Sequel lets you talk to it using Datasets, or Models, which have relationships and all the expected hooks, or you can use literal SQL. It works with Rails, but doesn't expect Rails, so you can easily incorporate it into small Ruby tools running at the command-line or in the background. We have a bunch of little apps like that.

Comment: Ok, I will have a look at sequel in future projects :)